# How linker selects .lib files to inlclude to build?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dependencies, cgal

Some not very meaningful backround: I'm trying to build CGAL using Visual Studio 2010. It is dependent on GMP and MPFR libraries. I'm building my project dependent on CGAL.

When building my project, I have linker error:

```
error LNK1104: cannot open file 'gmp-vc100-mt-sgd.lib'
```

However, I told CGAL to use GMP in file gmp.lib. And it is indeed used. But somehow linker additionally wants gmp-vc100-mt-sgd.lib. So, 'gmp-vc100-mt-sgd.lib' is default name and I changed it to 'gmp.lib' by altering some CGAL configuration .h file. I've checked all possible places:

- There is no such lib in Linker->Additional Dependencies in my project
- There is no References from my project to this lib
- Above is right for all projects in my solution
- There are no `#pragma comment(lib, "gmp-vc100-mt-sgd.lib")` directives in any included .h files (I've generated .i preprocessor output for all files in my project)

I've tried to rebuild CGAL and rebuild my solution with no result - linker still wants old 'gmp-vc100-mt-sgd.lib' file.

I'm stuck. Are there any other options to check? Any other sources where additional .lib dependencies come from? The only mentions of gmp-vc100-mt-sgd.lib are in CGAL .lib and .obj files under /DEFAULTLIB: directive. I searched through all files in CGAL solution to find mention of this magic gmp-vc100-mt-sgd.lib name with no result.

I checked every #pragma directive in .i file to ensure name gmp-vc100-mt-sgd.lib is not split in parts so I cannot find it. It's absolutely not presented there.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried renaming `gmp.lib` to `gmp-vc100-mt-sgd.lib` to check what happens?

Comment: did you do a fulltext search on "gmp-vc100-mt-sgd" on the entire project?  Also there is a way to capture the full command line given to the linked during the build process, try doing that.

Comment: are you using cmake to generate the solution?

Comment: @karlphillip yes, all works fine in this case.

Comment: @MK I've checked linker command line for my project: there is no mention of gmp-vc100-mt-sgd in it. And I've tried to search it through entire project and though all files in the directory with no result.

Comment: Do you have a project in your solution which builds any of these gmp libs?  And is that project by any chance marked as a dependency of the project you are building?  There is some magic that happens in that case which I do not understand.

Comment: @sloriot Yes, CGAL solution is generated using cmake-gui. And I've specified GMP_LIBRARIES key in CMAKE like "libgmp.lib". Seems like this key is simply ignored.

Comment: @MK GMP is built separately using cygwin, my project knows nothing about it.

Comment: See [this post](https://lists-sop.inria.fr/sympa/arc/cgal-discuss/2012-02/msg00111.html).

Comment: Suggested `CGAL_NO_AUTOLINK_GMP` macro is used to disable default linkage with name `gmp-vc100-mt-sgd.lib`. Instead, I overridden this name to `gmp.lib`, so defining macro have no effect in my case.

Comment: I just tried and in cmake if CGAL_AUTO_LINK_GMP is False then the lib looked for are gmp.lib or libgmp-10.lib. So should be working in your case.

Comment: @sloriot I tried to define CGAL_AUTO_LINK_GMP before including CGAL in my project - it still wants gmp-vc100-mt-sgd.lib in this case. Obviously, something is different in your case. The question is - what? And why gmp.lib is looked for after defining this macro? It should require manual linkage in this case.

Comment: I am talking about the cmake option CGAL_AUTO_LINK_GMP.

Comment: @sloriot This option will merely define or undef this flag in config.h file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out. The problem really was in this /DEFAULTLIB I found inside CGAL.lib file.

It turned out, when Visual Studio is building .lib file and encounters `#pragma comment` directive it leaves some instructions how to link this library. As I understand, it just tells the linker to use [/DEFAULTLIB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/229a6ysd%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) option when linking with it. And then linker tries to add this library in search list, even if it has no unresolved externals.

So I was trying to remove `#pragma comment` directive when building my project, but I should have tried to remove it when building CGAL project itself. The latter works fine.